# nvlink error : Undefined reference to * in 'Debug/*.cu.obj' (CUDA Separate Compilation, Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I have a very simple string class declared and defined in StringT.cu and StringT.cpp respectively.

**StringT.cu**

```
#ifndef STRING_T_CU
#define STRING_T_CU

#include "cuda_runtime.h"

class StringT
{
public:
   static const int MAX_LEN = 15;

   __host__ __device__ StringT(char const * s);
   __host__ __device__ ~StringT();
   __host__ __device__ char* Get();

private:
   char* str;
};

#endif
```

**StringT.cpp**

```
#include "StringT.cu"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

StringT::StringT(char const * s)
{
   str = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN + 1);
   int k;
   for (k = 0; *s != NULL; ++s, ++k) {
      if (k > MAX_LEN) {
         break;
      }
      str[k] = *s;
   }
   str[k] = '\0';
}

StringT::~StringT()
{
   free(str);
}

char* StringT::Get()
{
   return str;
}
```

I want to make a simple call to the class in kernel.cu.

**kernel.cu**

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include "StringT.cu"
#include "CudaUtil.h"

__global__ void kernel()
{
   StringT s("aa");
   printf("%s", s.Get());
}

int main()
{
   kernel <<< 1, 1 >>> ();
   checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
   checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

   return 0;
}
```

However this code fails to compile, giving errors like:

> 1>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN7StringTC1EPKc' in 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj'
>
> 1>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN7StringT3GetEv' in 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj'
>
> 1>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN7StringTD1Ev' in 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj'

As you can see all of the methods are defined. I have also tried changing the Runtime Library as instructed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919045/nvlink-error-undefined-reference-when-trying-to-write-to-text-file) post. I should add that I enabled relocatable device code as I am planning to use dynamic parallelism. Meanwhile, I did come across [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#code-changes-for-separate-compilation) document and found some instructions in the "Using Separate Compilation in CUDA" section. However, I am using visual studio for this project and not sure how exactly to change the compiler settings. I tried adding all sorts of things to

> C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options
>
> CUDA C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options
>
> Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options
>
> CUDA Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options

But still didn't get it to work. Does any one have any clue?

**Edited**
I renamed the files containing the declaration and definition of the string class:

**StringT.cuh**

```
#ifndef STRING_T_CUH
#define STRING_T_CUH

#include "cuda_runtime.h"

class StringT
{
public:
   static const int MAX_LEN = 15;

   __host__ __device__ StringT(char const * s);
   __host__ __device__ ~StringT();
   __host__ __device__ char* Get();

private:
   char* str;
};

#endif
```

**StringT.cu**

```
#include "StringT.cuh"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

__host__ __device__ StringT::StringT(char const * s)
{
   str = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN + 1);
   int k;
   for (k = 0; *s != NULL; ++s, ++k) {
      if (k > MAX_LEN) {
         break;
      }
      str[k] = *s;
   }
   str[k] = '\0';
}

__host__ __device__ StringT::~StringT()
{
   free(str);
}

__host__ __device__ char* StringT::Get()
{
   return str;
}
```

I created the project with the template that came with the vs integration option from CUDA 8.0 installation, changed relocatable code to true and arch to sm_61, compute_61 (I have GTX 1080 Ti).

The error messages, after I changed output verbosity to detailed, were:

> 1>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN7StringTC1EPKc' in 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj'
>
> 1>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN7StringT3GetEv' in 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj'
>
> 1>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN7StringTD1Ev' in 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj'

On the other hand, I did manage to compile and run the code by extending one of the sample projects, "simpleSeparateCompilation". However, there were not any extra command line options that I can see. This works for me for now, but of course I have not solved the original problem.

Comment: You cannot have the definitions of the class member functions in a .cpp file. There will never be any code compiled for the GPU if you do that

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I renamed the .cpp file to "StringTDef.cu" I get an error like: The command "nvcc ...." existed with code 255. But the same code compiles works without the __host__ __device__ qualifier, but ofc no device code generated. I want to separate the declaration and definition since I need to include the header in different files and avoiding multiple definition error. How should I do that?

Comment: The error you quoted isn't anything other than indicating that the compilation failed. Can you edit the updated code and actual error into you question. In general you *must* have the definitions in a .cu file annotated `__device__ __host__` otherwise it won't work. You can have declaration and definitions separated, that is no problem.  Whatever other errors you are getting are not related to the changes I have suggested

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. As for the kernel.cu file, I updated the code to include "StringT.cuh".

Comment: You will need to use separate compilation and device linking if your intention is to use the device functions in the class in a kernel defined in a different .cu file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using visual studio, renaming from .cpp to .cu and/or .h to .cuh do/does not work.

In order to generate device code, one has to add "CUDA C/C++ File" or "CUDA C/C++ Header" as oppose to "C++ File" and "Header File", in addition to enabling

1. relocatable device code (Properties -> Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code)
2. device linking (Properties -> Configuration Properties -> CUDA Linker -> Common -> Perform Device Link)